# Custom Notification Bar in Android

Tags: android, layout, notification-bar

For my android application my requirement is to implement the Custom Notification Bar in my layout. When user drag this Custom notification bar then icons will be visible. This custom notification bar is look like notification bar at the bottom in the Facebook Android Application. If anyone knows how to do this then please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"/>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content">

        <Button
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drawer Handle"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:text="This is the content of the drawer"/>

    </SlidingDrawer>

</FrameLayout>
```

### Update:

Nice tutorial with detailed description: [Android: Damn that Sliding Drawer](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I miss this control in the android.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper No probs, but go through this control this time so you dont have to look for this view in future. Cheers :)

Comment: This will run the application fine.