# Notification Bar (or similar) inside activity

Tags: android, view, android-notification-bar

Is there a way to create a layout like the notification bar (the sliding bar that can be dropped from the top of the working area in Android, and which holds general notifications) inside of an activity?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a sliding drawer and then build up from there.
Here is a nice post with example code [Custom Notification Bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952015/custom-notification-bar-in-android)